# VHDL Parametric case

Tags: vhdl, hardware

I've some problem with my synthesis tool. I'm writing a module and I'm tryng to make it parametric and scalable. In my design I've a FSM and some counters. The counters have a parametric width ( they are function of the width of the datapath ). The problem is that I'm using that counter to drive a case statements. The synthesizer gives me back this error :

> 2049990   ERROR - (VHDL-1544) array type case expression must be of a locally static subtype

I've also tried to use subtype, but it doesnt work. The declaration is :

```
constant LENGTH_COUNTER_WORD : integer := integer(ceil(log2(real(WIDTH_DATA/WIDTH_WORD))));

subtype type_counter_word is std_logic_vector( LENGTH_COUNTER_WORD - 1 downto 0);
signal counter_word : std_logic_vector( LENGTH_COUNTER_WORD - 1 downto 0);
```

The case :

```
case type_counter_word'(counter_word) is
    when (others => '1') =>
        do_stuff();
    when others =>
        do_other_stuff();
end case;
```

I cannot switch to VHDL-2008. I've read I can use variable, but I'd like to find a different solution, if it exists. I cannot imagine there isn't any way to give parameters to synthesizer before the synthesis.

Comment: Which exact line of code raises the error? Also, you say synthesis gives the error ... are you sure this worked correctly in simulation?

Comment: @BrianDrummond - `case type_counter_word'(counter_word) is` raises the error, and it's not uniquely a synthesis issue, it's how to insure case coverage, and no it won't work in simulation. The type of the expression must be locally static to insure choice coverage and a variable declared as type_counter_word won't work if either WIDTH_DATA or WIDTH_WORD is a generic, which is globally static and not locally static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in VHDL-2008. You can only work around it in earlier standards by using cascaded `if` statements (with the attendant priority logic). Variables don't make a difference when determining if choices are locally static.

Comment: If I use the if statements, my design will be slower....is it correct ? The only ways to avoid this is to use a fixed number for the data path width, or change synthesis tool.

Comment: It depends on the logic involved. If you're just using the single case testing all-ones with the others case catching the remainder like in your example then there is no effective difference compared to the logic synthesized for an if-else. The priority logic only kicks in when you have more than one case to evaluate and even then it won't always be part of the critical path. If it is, you can register the comparisons and test the Boolean results on the next cycle.

Comment: If you're targeting modern FPGAs with wide LUTs, the multiple cascaded muxes implementing the priority logic of if-elsif-else will tend to map into a single LUT in which case there is no real speed difference compared to the decoder synthesized by a case statement. Many of the "rules" of digital logic minimization assume the target is discrete gates, an ASIC, or similar and they don't always apply in FPGAs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how complicated your `do_stuff()` and `do_other_stuff()` operations are, but if you are just doing simple signal assignments, you could look into the `and_reduce()` function in the `ieee.std_logic_misc` library.

As an example:

```
output <= '1' when and_reduce(type_counter_word'(counter_word)) = '1' else '0';
```

Otherwise, as Kevin's answer suggests, a process block using `if` statements might be your best option.

Comment: I've several case statements and they usually don't have only 2 possibily cases but more, so i can't use and_reduce and I'm not sure that the and_reduce() could fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

About the time of Kevin's good enough answer, I had written this to demonstrate:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity counterword is
    generic ( 
        WIDTH_DATA: positive := 16;
        WIDTH_WORD: positive := 8
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of counterword is

    constant LENGTH_COUNTER_WORD : integer := 
        integer(ceil(log2(real(WIDTH_DATA/WIDTH_WORD))));
    subtype type_counter_word is 
            std_logic_vector( LENGTH_COUNTER_WORD - 1 downto 0);
    signal counter_word : std_logic_vector( LENGTH_COUNTER_WORD - 1 downto 0);
    procedure do_stuff is
        begin
        end;
    procedure do_other_stuff is
        begin
        end;
begin
UNLABELLED:
    process (counter_word)
    begin
        -- case  type_counter_word'(counter_word) is
        --     when (others => '1') =>
        --         do_stuff;
        --     when others =>
        --         do_other_stuff;
        -- end case;
        if counter_word = type_counter_word'(others => '1') then
            do_stuff;
        else
            do_other_stuff;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Note because type_counter_word is a subtype you can provide the subtype constraints in a qualified expression for the aggregate:

```
    if counter_word = type_counter_word'(others => '1') then
```

From IEEE Std 1076-2008:

> 9.3.5 Qualified expressions

A qualified expression is a basic operation (see 5.1) that is used to explicitly state the type, and possibly the subtype, of an operand that is an expression or an aggregate.

This example analyzes, elaborates and simulates while doing nothing in particular. It'll call the sequential procedure statement do_other_stuff, which does nothing.

(For do_stuff and do_other stuff, empty interface lists aren't allowed).